# Unique constraint with DataNucleus discriminator based multitenancy

Tags: datanucleus, multi-tenant

Is it possible to specify unicity contraint on the column of a persistable class when using [multitenancy by discriminator](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/rdbms/multitenancy.html) where the constraint would apply on a per-tenant basis only. (i.e. OK to have same value for different tenant) ?

Or should this be enforced at the application level ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, the condition is to specify the unique constraint on the column, since the "internal" tenant column will not be recognized as a member.

Example :

```
  <extension vendor-name="datanucleus" key="multitenancy-column-name" value="tenant"/>
  <extension vendor-name="datanucleus" key="multitenancy-column-length" value="255"/>

  <unique name="UNIQUE_NAME_PER_TENANT">
    <column name="tenant"/>
    <column name="name"/>
  </unique>
```